# How could my strings be encoded ASCII when all is set on utf8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Character encoding is always a little bit tricky in languages with special letters.

MySQL database server is under  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

the collation is utf8-general-ci

when, using mysqli, i get some data from the database  :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    foreach ($row as $field=>$value){
        print(mb_detect_encoding($value).' '.$value."<br/>");
    }
}
```

characters are encoded ASCII not UTF-8. Where does it come from ?

More infos : 
My Apache AddDefaultCharset is utf-8

the encoding charset for the html page is utf-8

I build the database with a script exported from another database which is utf-8 too

PS : I tried the mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8") but it does not change anything.

I really would like to know when and how the data is encoded ASCII ?

Thank you

PS 2 : this is the result I have with the mb_detect_encoding

```
ASCII ESSAI
ASCII 34
ASCII Bonjour
ASCII 41
UTF-8 ���������������
```

and the warning from DOMElement : Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute() [domelement.setattribute]: string is not in UTF-8

PS 3 : the problem is with the UTF-8 data.

In the database I have èèèèèèèèèèèèèèèèèèèèè

if I use utf8_encode around the string, I have no more problem and this as a result :

```
ASCII ESSAI
ASCII 34
ASCII Bonjour
ASCII 41
UTF-8 èèèèèèèèèèèèèèè
ASCII 43
```

So obviously my utf8 string is a utf8 string (see mb_detect_encoding) but the value has been changed somehow

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so an ASCII string *is also* a valid UTF-8 string.  A UTF-8 encoded string that uses characters only in the ASCII set is also a valid ASCII string.

Comment: @cdhowie Unless it's an [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) - which is rarely the case nowadays.

Comment: @IdanArye Well, Extended ASCII is not ASCII (it's a superset), so I stand by my statement.

Comment: I use DOMElement class and I have a warning saying that my string is not a utf-8 encoded string. Obviously it does not think that ASCII string is a utf-8 string

Comment: @mlwacosmos Please `var_dump()` the string and add it to your question.

Comment: How does it looks like in the database ?

Comment: @cdhowie No you are right ASCII is the same : the problem is not here.. see PS 3

Comment: in the database it looks OK

Comment: I mean, what is the string in the database ?

Comment: Yet another example why *charset detection* is simply not working. There's no problem here, you're only demonstrating the impossibility of guessing charsets.

Comment: @deceze it cannot be... I would not believe that

Comment: You would not believe that charset guessing is unreliable? Or are you being sarcastic? Sorry, can't tell.

Comment: No, it is not sarcastic, I dont believe that you can set the database charset, the collation ... and all for nothing because it would be undetectable

Comment: Please read http://kunststube.net/encoding for an introduction to what encodings are. Hopefully this should explain why figuring out what encoding a random blob of bytes represents is fundamentally not accurately possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I replaced mysqli with PDO

It works. The utf8 string is not changed...

So the problem is with mysqli (dont use that again)

@deceze : you can detect charset and it works good when everything is set right

Comment: mysqli works just as well as PDO for getting correctly encoded UTF-8 strings from the database, you were just missing some detail. Once strings are in PHP there's no difference between a string from PDO and mysqli or anywhere else.

Comment: It seems to be... at least by default because it works with PDO and not mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

As said 7 bits ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so "Bonjour" is detected as ASCII, "café, 3€" as UTF-8 (though you would see "caf" and ", 3").

Passing a variable filled from SQL immediately to the DOMElement (without `utf8_encode`) *should* work.

Comment: you are right, this is what I thought too but obviously although the data has the good format in the database, when I get it through mysqli, it is not the same : small squares... this is why DOMElement cannot read it

Comment: Did you look in the database with some other tool? MySQLAdmin or such. Or simply a database dump (mysqldump); can be limited to a single table.

Comment: same with MySQL Workbench

Comment: And there the texts in the database are okay? So it is the reading, not the original writing. _Then we have to wait for a more experienced answer._

Comment: it is like something reencode the character (in the driver maybe...) I should try with PDO